# Show $\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]2}-\frac{1}{2(\sqrt[3]2-1)}+\left(\frac{9}{2\sqrt[3]4}-\frac{9}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that:

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]2}-\frac{1}{2(\sqrt[3]2-1)}+\left(\frac{9}{2\sqrt[3]4}-\frac{9}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

---

The LHS is irrational number and RHS is rational number. May be this is almost a $\frac{1}{2}$. 
According to the calculator it is a $\frac{1}{2}$

I tried to cube both sides but it looked too messy.

Comment: What is the source of the problem?

Comment: Do you know the left is irrational?  The pieces are, but adding them might make it rational.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E(2%2F3)-1%2F2%2F(cbrt(2)-1)%2Bcbrt(9%2F2%2Fcbrt(4)-9%2F4)) claims it is exactly $1/2$

Comment: Maple also claims it is exactly $1/2$.

Comment: So what you want is the let LHS=x and you will show x is 1/2. after that what you want to do is to have $(\frac{9}{2a}-\frac{9}{4})^{\frac{1}{3}=k-(\frac{2}{a}-\frac{1}{2(a-1)}$. Now you can cube both sides. After you cube you can apply log to both sides (with the intention to exponentiate). Note I use a as the cube root of 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try. 
Note that $$(1+\sqrt[3]{2})^3 = 3(1+\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4}).$$

Now we have:

$$LHS = \sqrt[3]{4} - \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt[3]{4} + \sqrt[3]{2} + 1) + \left(\frac{9}{4(\sqrt[3]{4}+\sqrt[3]{2}+1) }\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} = \sqrt[3]{4} - \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt[3]{4} + \sqrt[3]{2} + 1) + \left(\frac{27}{4(\sqrt[3]{2}+1)^3 }\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} = \sqrt[3]{4} - \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt[3]{4} + \sqrt[3]{2} + 1) + \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4}(\sqrt[3]{2}+1)} = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt[3]{4} - \sqrt[3]{2} - 1) + \frac{\sqrt[3]{2}(\sqrt[3]{4}-\sqrt[3]{2}+1)}{2} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's the proof I would use... note that I skip a few steps, specifically on simplifying the far right term on the LHS. Likewise, I apologize for any typos... my computer crashed thrice while writing this
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]2}-\frac{1}{2(\sqrt[3]2-1)}+\left(\frac{9}{2\sqrt[3]4}-\frac{9}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$= 2^{2/3} - \frac{1}{2(\sqrt[3]2-1)} + \left(\frac{9}{4}\left(2^{1/3} - 1\right)\right)^{1/3}$$
$$= 2^{2/3} - \frac{1}{2(\sqrt[3]2-1)} + 1+\frac{1}{2^{2/3}}-\frac{1}{2^{1/3}}$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\left(2^{2/3}(2-1) - \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]2-1} + 2+2^{1/3}\right)$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\left(2^{2/3} - \frac{1}{2^{1/3}-1} + 2+2^{1/3}\right)$$
$$= \frac{1}{2(\sqrt[3]2-1)}\left(2-2^{2/3} - 1 + 2^{4/3} - 2+2^{2/3} - 2^{1/3}\right)$$
$$= \frac{1}{2(2^{1/3}-1)}\left( 2^{1/3} - 1\right)$$
$$=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Note here that the LHS *is* rational... the product of irrational numbers can trivially yield a rational number (take $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2} = 2$) as can related operations